# Most efficient way to evolve?

Tags: pokemon-go

Soo I was thinking about this all night and I think I know how it works but im not sure, for example when i want to have a good pidgeot I should try to catch like a 10Cp Pidgey, so he would basicly be lvl 1 I guess? And when I have this pidgey I should evolve him into a pidgeotto and after that pidgeot, WITHOUT powering him up sooo he would be like 60 CP I guess? since he would get some CP thanks to the evolution.

And when I finally have this "lvl1" pidgeot I should max upgrade him? This way he gets the most powerfull moveset right??